# Touch/Tap event on SurfacePro with DojoToolkit not working

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have following code (see https://jsfiddle.net/1acx22tx/1/):

My HTML

```
<div id="myElement" style="padding: 20px; background: #abcdef;">tap me (only 
works with touch device)</div>
```

My (shortened) Script

```
require({...}, ["dojo/on", "dgrid/util/touch"], function(on, touchUtil){
    on(document.getElementById("myElement"), touchUtil.tap, function(ev) {
        alert("TAP WORKS!");
    }); 
});
```

I want to detect a TAP event using the dgrid touch util (i have my content in a dgrid, the example is stripped down to the necessary elements). I cannot use the `touch.press` because this would fire a "click" of the element when scrolling in the table.

I now have a working (in my eyes ugly) "solution" (on Desktop, IPhone/Safari and SurfacePro) using dojo/has "feature detection" that looks like the following:

```
require({...}, ["dojo/on", "dojo/has", "dojo/touch", "dgrid/util/touch"], function(on, has, touch, touchUtil){

    if (has("touch")) {
        if (has("safari")) {
            clickEvent = touchUtil.selector(".dgrid-row-table", touchUtil.tap);
        } else {
            clickEvent = touch.release;
        }
    } else {
        clickEvent = ".dgrid-row-table:click";
    }
    on(document.getElementById("myDgrid"), clickEvent, function(event) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm not very happy with this solution. Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong in the first place?

Comment: [touchUtil.tap](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/util/touch.js#L97) is a function and propably `on` won't listen on it. Would replacing it with `"touchstart"` (as is in function in link) help you?

Comment: on Safari/IPhone this is working well, so i think it's not the problem. And moreover, `touchstart` does not work on the SurfacePro.